# fwrite not putting \r\n in my file (for the data provided in textareas comin from a post)

Tags: php

im trying to make a function that saves my configuration data for an automatic email.

the data is coming from textareas so $_POST and put into this function.

My saving function is not saving the \r\n caracteres so no line breaks. so when i send a email the full message in 1 big string with no line breaks...

if i open the file it is saved with spaces instead of it all being on 1 line.

```
if ($_POST['gdwemail_obj']!="") { $gdwEConfig['gdwemail_obj'] = $_POST['gdwemail_obj']; }
if ($_POST['gdwemail_mes']!="") { $gdwEConfig['gdwemail_mes'] = $_POST['gdwemail_mes']; }
saveEConfig($gdwEConfig);



function saveEConfig($post) {
    $gdw_conffile = 'components'.DS.'com_gdwformulaire'.DS.'included'.DS.'econfig.gdw.php';
    $gdw_confopen = fopen($gdw_conffile,'w+');
    $gdw_cfgput  = '<?php';
    $gdw_cfgput .= ' $gdwEconf = array(); ';

    $gdw_cfgput .= ' $gdwEconf[\'gdwemail\'] = "'.$post['gdwemail'].'"; ';
    $gdw_cfgput .= ' $gdwEconf[\'gdwemail_obj\'] = "'.$post['gdwemail_obj'].'"; ';
    $gdw_cfgput .= ' $gdwEconf[\'gdwemail_mes\'] = "'.$post['gdwemail_mes'].'"; ';

    $gdw_cfgput .= '?>';
    if (!fwrite($gdw_confopen, $gdw_cfgput)) {
        echo "<script> alert('ERROR: Can't save configuration file, please verify CHMOD access on \'administrator/components/com_ai/\' for write access.'); window.history.go(-1); </script>\n";
        exit;
    }    
    fclose($gdw_confopen);
}
```

the output looks like this:

```
    <?php $gdwEconf = array();  $gdwEconf['gdwemail'] = "j.robidas@geantduweb.ca";  $gdwEconf['gdwemail_obj'] = "Réservation pour le cours {courschoisi} a été reçus";  $gdwEconf['gdwemail_mes'] = "Cher {nomdemandeur},

Votre demande de réservation a été reçus avec succès.

Information pour votre sélection:
{courschoisi}
{dateheurechoisi}

Merci
L'équipe de Belle vie de chien"; ?>
```

Comment: nope i droped the issue for the moment i will get back to it...

Answer (score 2):

Because you aren't actually including \r\n in your $gdw_cfgput .= ... lines.

Answer (score 1):

Your not asking it to put in any line breaks into your `$gdw_cfgput` string.

```
$gdw_cfgput  = '<?php';
$gdw_cfgput .= "\r\n";
$gdw_cfgput .= ' $gdwEconf = array(); ';
```

Note the double quotes, which tell PHP to interpret the `\r\n` as a line break.

Comment: nono the $post['gdwemail'] $post['gdwemail_obj'] $post['gdwemail_mes'] are $_POST values coming from textareas with the content that has the line breaksthat  i need.

Comment: @StiGMaT : The only $_POST variable I see that is *probably* a text area based on the key name is that gdwemail_mes which I can see from your output, shows linebreaks just fine.  But those other post values look like they are probably text fields or something and then there are your lines before that that are just hardcoded that also don't have any linebreaks added.

Comment: how do you turn `$_POST` into `$post` your sanitising function might be removing line breaks, mine does!

Comment: if ($_POST['gdwemail_obj']!="") { $gdwEConfig['gdwemail_obj'] = $_POST['gdwemail_obj']; }
   if ($_POST['gdwemail_mes']!="") { $gdwEConfig['gdwemail_mes'] = $_POST['gdwemail_mes']; }
   saveEConfig($gdwEConfig);

Comment: Can you edit your post to include your whole script? There is no reason for line beaks to be stripped.

Answer (score 1):

Your file doesn't contain linebreaks because you didn't specify any. You assemble $gdw_cfgput, but don't append any `. "\r\n";`. If you want to add it, you could use `. PHP_EOL;` btw.

A better alternative however would be if you used `var_export()` for generating your output file. It seems you have one coherent array, and var_export would simplify outputting that.

```
$config = var_export($_POST, true);
fwrite($f, "<?php\n\n\$gdwEconf = $config;\n?>");
```